# Running pfsense on a xenserver - Random network drops?

Tags: router, xen, pfsense

I have a Xenserver with two NIC's. The first one is connected directly to my buildings router, and the second one is connected to my a switch powering my home LAN, and is set up as the management interface.

I've installed pfsense as a VM on the xenserver with access to both NIC's, and defined #1 as WAN and #2 as LAN. This seemed to be working fine - I'm still able to configure the xenserver via a static IP I set, and the rest of my network is happily getting DHCP and is routing traffic through pfsense. Even Xen has internet through pfsense.

IP's from the ISP are given via DHCP, as are DNS settings and such.

This seemed to be working fine, but now every few hours I suddenly lose internet connectivity on pfsense and my LAN. Occasionally, packets get through, but the majority doesn't. At first I thought this was an ARP conflict (pfsense and xen trying to request the same WAN ip), but I didn't see this occurring in tcpdump so I ruled it out.

It doesn't matter what I do - Restarting VM's, messing around from inside pfense/xen, the only way to get stable internet back seems to be rebooting the entire xen server.

What can cause this? Especially, what can cause it after a few hours of perfectly fine internet? It doesn't seem to be DHCP expiring causing it as it does that several times and is fine. Is there anywhere I can look for logs?

Edit: I've noticed that running tcpdump on the WAN port on the Xen when I DO have internet I get very, very little data. However, after the internet stops working, I get significantly more throughput on tcpdump. I assume this means at some point the xen is trying to lease the IP or something, but I'm not really sure how to confirm this or stop it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was fixed by downgrading to Xenserver 7.2. This seems to be an issue with 7.3 specifically.